# (Cycles) Texture working on Viewport but not Render

Tags: texturing

Texture sometimes show the half, sometimes doesn't show at all.

Viewport
[image: Viewport]

Render

[image]

Blend-Exchange
[image]

Comment: Maybe sharing the blend file will help us to troubleshoot your issue. Use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com) to share the blend file

Comment: done _______________

Comment: I've figured it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is quite simple my friend (and a bit funny) :D

You hid the "Circle.001" object in the viewport, but not in the renders. So when you render it, it overlaps with the other piece of the padlock (Circle) causing it to look white since it doesn't have a material on it.

**Just hide it in renders by pressing the "Disable in renders" toggle:**
[image]

**Result after disabling it in render:**
[image]

Be more careful and mindful while you're working. I was happy to help though :)

Comment: oh, thanks! I was following a tutorial and forgot to delete that.